# MAPI - put restriction / sort on parent folder to affect all subfolders

Tags: c++, email, outlook, mapi

similarly to outlook's search form, where in the search box i can affect(search) all sub-folders, is it possible to do something similar using MAPI's API without iterating all IMAPIFolder recursively?

The reason i'm asking this, i'd like to retrieve top 10 mails from all subfolders

**EDIT**: I know such solution is possible by creating hidden search folder, but is it an overkill?

**EDIT2**: Searching using Search Folder yields results by sub folders / lables as opposed to Outlook's search box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot do that unless you create a search folder.

Why not simply loop through all subfolders, sort each contents table and retrieve top 10 items?

Comment: But what happens in a scenario where i need to retrieve top(newest) X mails? this means i will need to implement a merge-sort after im done iterating through all subfolders

Comment: yes, which is easy to with if you are only retrieving 10 items from each folder.

Comment: 10 is just an example, could also be 1000